# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : polygons require at least 4 points when st_cast('POLYGON'),

Tags: r

My data comes from  OpenStreetMap and GADM data to identify areas in Italy without roads. I've created lists of roads, and I've downloaded the boundaries of Italian regions, dividing Italy into 5 main regions.

I have created two lists: region and road:'region' variable contains GADM data, while 'road' contains OpenStreetMap data.

I've defined two functions for this task:

```
road_buffer <- function(road, region) {
  buffer_strade <- road%>%
    st_buffer(dist = 1000) %>%
    st_union() %>%
    st_difference(region) %>%
    st_cast("POLYGON")
  return(buffer_road)
}

road_less <- function(region, buffer_road) {
  road_eless_patch <- region %>%
    st_union() %>%
    st_difference(buffer_road) %>%
    st_cast("POLYGON")
  return(road_less_patch)
}
```

I've  updated the loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(road)) {
  buffer <- road_buffer(road[[i]], region[[i]]) 
  bufferless <- road_less(region[[i]], buffer_road)
  roadless[[i]] <- bufferless
}
```

However, I'm encountering an error, specifically within the 'road_eless' function:

```
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : polygons require at least 4 points  when st_cast('POLYGON')
```

I've been contemplating the removal of geometries with fewer than 3 points within this function but have encountered challenges in doing so. Can anyone offer assistance? Thank you very much for your help!